# DataGridView Получить измененные данные без перехода на другую строку

Tags: c#, datagridview

Подскажите как решить проблему.
На форме лежит DataGridView, EditMode EditOnKeystrokeOrF2. Загружаю какие-то данные, далее меняю в какой-то ячейке, и потом не покидая ячейку, не нажимая Enter 
 и тп, просто что-то вбил и сразу хочу сохранить изменения например по кнопке.

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        dGvTables.EndEdit();
        db.SaveMess(((DataTable)dGvTables.DataSource).GetChanges());            
    }
```

но ((DataTable)dGvTables.DataSource).GetChanges() возвращает null. Как зафиксировать изменения, что бы возвращались изменения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так работает

```
    dGvTables.EndEdit();
    dGvTables.BindingContext[dGvTables.DataSource].EndCurrentEdit();
    if (dataSet1.HasChanges() == true) {
        db.SaveErrMess(((DataTable)dGvTables.DataSource).GetChanges());
```